# Visual Studio think that winform is a variable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, variables, types

So i've just started learning C#, and I came across a error saying that Form5 "is a variable but is used like a type". I have shown the page of code that has the error, but if you want to look at the bigger picture, here's my github repo ( I am a totally noob at gihub, so if anything is mispelled or totally wrong, I'm Sorry! : https://github.com/ValorZard/Chocobomb

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace animal_years
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            */

            Form Form1 = new Form1();

            Form1.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form Form3 = new Form3();

            Form3.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form2 = new Form2();

            Form2.Show();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form4 = new Form4();

            Form4.Show();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Form Form5 = new Form5();
            Form5.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your constructor for `Form5()`?

Comment: Don't declare variable with the same name as you declare the class. `Form5` is class name and you are also declaring variable with same name

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to name your variables the same as the class names? It would make your code easier to debug if you would avoid class names as variable names (it won't fix your problem, but may reveal the issue)

Answer (score 4):

> Form5 "is a variable but is used like a type"

That is precisely correct. And clear. You're using the type name `Form5` (which is a terrible, undescriptive name by the way) as a variable name too. A simple alternative is to write `new Form5().Show();` -- why do you need a local variable in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Your class name in form5.cs file is outputDescriptionLabel. So you have to call that class name here. Use below code:

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        outputDescriptionLabel f = new outputDescriptionLabel();
        f.Show();
    }
```